# Does sonar cloud support decorative messages for Python in a GitHub PR with workflow?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, workflow, sonarcloud

I used the generic workflow https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action-samples/blob/generic/.github/workflows/build.yml as suggested in the docs.

But I'm not receiving the message from the bot in the repository, code is analyzed just fine and I can see it in the website.

#### workflow

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main", "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main", "develop" ]
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  pull-requests: read # allows SonarCloud to decorate PRs with analysis results

 
jobs:
  sonar_cloud_report:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    
    steps:
      - uses : actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ./.github/actions/dependencies
      - uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}   # Generate a token on Sonarcloud.io, add it to the secrets of this repo with the name SONAR_TOKEN (Settings > Secrets > Actions > add new repository secret)
        with:
          # Additional arguments for the sonarcloud scanner
          args:
            # Unique keys of your project and organization. You can find them in SonarCloud > Information (bottom-left menu)
            # mandatory
            -Dsonar.projectKey=XXX
            -Dsonar.organization=XXX
            -Dsonar.scm.provider=git
            # Comma-separated paths to directories containing main source files.
            #-Dsonar.sources= # optional, default is project base directory
            # When you need the analysis to take place in a directory other than the one from which it was launched
            #-Dsonar.projectBaseDir= # optional, default is .
            # Comma-separated paths to directories containing test source files.
            #-Dsonar.tests= # optional. For more info about Code Coverage, please refer to https://docs.sonarcloud.io/enriching/test-coverage/overview/
            # Adds more detail to both client and server-side analysis logs, activating DEBUG mode for the scanner, and adding client-side environment variables and system properties to the server-side log of analysis report processing.
            #-Dsonar.verbose= # optional, default is false
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

#### sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=XXX
sonar.organization=XXX
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml


# This is the name and version displayed in the SonarCloud UI.
#sonar.projectName=XXX
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
#sonar.sources=.

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: What message from the bot are you expecting?

Comment: The decorative message from the bot https://docs.sonarcloud.io/improving/pull-request-analysis/ section "Pull request decoration"